# Using chain rule and differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm working through Vector Calculus by Tromba & Marsden in preparation for my MGREs next month. I'm stuck on the following problem.

Show that $\,d/dx \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy = f(x,x) + \int_0^x \,df/dx (x,y)\,dy$

This is what I've tried so far:

1) Let $F(x,x) = \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy$. By the chain rule I have $\,d/dx (F(x,x)) = \,dF/dx + \,dF/dx = \int_0^x \,df/dx (x,y)\,dy + \int_0^x \,df/dx (x,y)\,dy$.

2)$D(\int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy) = \int_0^x \,D f(x,y)\,dy = \int_0^x \,df/dx(x,y)\,dy + \int_0^x \,df/dy(x,y)\,dy = \int_0^x \,df/dx(x,y)\,dy + f(x,x)$

by the second fundamental theorem of calc.

The second attempt doesn't work since I need the derivative with respect to $x$. I'm pretty lost on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should let

$$F(a,b) := \int_0^a f(b,y)\, dy.$$

Then $F_a(a,b) = f(b,a)$ and $F_b(a,b) = \int_0^a f_b(b,y)\, dy$. Now use the 2-D chain rule to get

$$\frac{d}{dx} F(x,x) = F_a(x,x) + F_b(x,x) = f(x,x) + \int_0^x f_x(x,y)\, dy.$$

Comment: I'm assuming by $F_a$ and $F_b$ you meant derivative with respect to a and b?

Comment: @Lupin Yes, that's right.